# Identifying that a file is being copied outside the computer in LKM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, system-calls

Assuming that i have Loadable-Kernel-Module inserted in linux-kernel and have hooked read, write, open and close functions. So now i can stop access to any file but i want to stop files from being copied outside the device like to a usb device, card, disk etc. The thing i want to know is that sitting in LKM and with function calls hooked how can i identify that a file is being written to external device?.

Also i want to know that which system calls are used during a copy operation ? I have idea that a program opens the file reads from it ( read system call) and then writes to second file( write system call) but i observed strange behavior when i was trying to stop write access to a file that a process which opens a file never calls write operation on that file for saving file (checked for pdf viewer).

If anybody have idea about this strange behavior or you have idea that how to stop writing to a file then please share it also.

Comment: Just don't mount the external device?

Comment: Leak protection involves monitoring of writing operations on all outgoing data carriers. It can't be solved by simply "tracking copying". So I voted to close this question as being similar to perpetuum mobile search.

Comment: "The thing i want to know is that sitting in LKM and with function calls hooked how can i identify that a file is being written to external device?" This is what i asked for not how to prevent leakage. And thanks for your encouraging behavior Mr @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp

Answer (score 1):

They could `mmap` it to do read/write. Or they could read the entire original file into memory, close it, then open the destination.

Or they could encrypt the file, then write it out to a new file on the USB.

Or they could do minor edits to the contents, then save it out.

Or they could use gvfs to access the network/USB device.

Or the user could reboot and copy the file in a different OS.

---

All that really highlights is that the problem is really difficult - a determined user will always find a way to extract data from a system they have access to.

You're best bet is just to prevent accidental leakage - so scan files after close on the removable media, and check they don't have contents you don't want leaked. Overwrite and delete if they do.

Or else block the devices from being mounted in the first place, and disable gvfs as well.

---

As to why your hook isn't intercepting the write(), either:

1. Your hook isn't actually intercepting the operation.
2. The application isn't using write() to put the content in a file.

Comment: and what about the behavior i mentioned. What if i just want to block write operation to a file? I have tried it using write system call hooking but it results in behavior i mentioned in my question.

Comment: For blocking write access I keep list of processes which has opened my file and never allows those processes to write it back but processes still can change file easily. Those processes never writes that file back through write system call but file is changed.